# Is $E=h\upsilon$ applicable to an electron

Tags: energy, particle-physics, wave-particle-duality

If we consider the wave nature of electron whose frequency is $\nu$,
is the equation $E=h\nu$ applicable to electrons?

Comment: Yes, it does so long as the electron is in an energy eigenstate (meaning that it has a single well defined energy). Stationary states/energy eigenstates of the wave function has a phase factor given by an exponential with an angular frequency given by E/h-bar, where h-bar is the (reduced) Planck constant. Rearranging and cancelling out common factors of 2 pi, you fet that E=hv, where v is the frequency. I think de Broglie was the first to propose that the formula E=hv applies to all particles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de Broglie equations relate the wavelength $\lambda$ to the momentum $p$, and frequency $\nu$ to the total energy $E$ of a *free particle*:
$$\boxed{\lambda=\frac{h}{p}; \ \ \ \ E=h\nu}$$
or
$$E=\hbar \omega , \  \ \ \mathbf{p}=\hbar\mathbf{k} $$

Reference : [Matter Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave)